# PHP Data Scraping

Tags: php, html

I would like to scrape some data from a website using PHP using

preg_match("/ /i/s", $contents, $matches);

The website I am trying to get data from looks like this

https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/?search_id=592135669&

I would like to scrape the line that says;

**Showing 1-17 of 17 results**

I want to use (.*?) to get the total number of properties (in this case 17) for a website to show this information separately.

How can I use preg_match when the data I am scraping varies according to the amount of properties available?

I look forward to any assistance.

David

Comment: I *think* you're looking for `preg_match_all()`, but those expressions are probably *way* too general for your purposes.

Comment: Please see: Section 3.4(g) - Without limiting the foregoing, you agree that when using the Platform you will not: use software or any other means to harvest information from the Platform; https://www.spareroom.co.uk/content/default/terms-uk

Comment: Well that’s out of the window now! Thanks for the notice on that Lawrence, will not go down that road then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the example page it looks like this line appears once on a page. If it appears multiple times you may want preg_match_all to return multiple results. Another tricky thing about doing this is changes that get made to a web page from time to time. So here is a solution that will work right now, but you can also tweak things to account for changes in the web page (something I can't tell from a single example):

```
preg_match( "#<.*?>\s*(\d+)\s*<.*?>\s+results#i",  $page, $results );
```

So I use the i flag to make it case insensitive. That way if they capitalize "results" or something it won't break.

```
<.*?>
```

Keep in mind that you are going to be getting the HTML code which has tags you can't see from the front. In this case there are strong tags around the total. But maybe they will change this to a different tag in the future? So I just used open/close angle brackets with wildcards for the contents. Oh and the question mark is so it's not greedy and stops at the closest angle bracket.

```
\s*
```

This looks for 0 or more spaces. Right now there is a single space between the strong tag and the total. What if they remove that space or add more? This should cover you in both cases.

```
(\d+)
```

The parenthesis is what captures content to the $results array. Inside it is saying 1 or more digits, so only numbers.

```
\s*
```

Like earlier, looking for 0 or more space characters.

```
<.*?>
```

This is to match the closing strong tag but takes account that they could later use a different closing tag.

```
\s+results
```

This is looking for one or more spaces before the word results. We know there has to be at least one, but they could make changes in the future that will put more spaces in there (even though the webpage will only display one).

$results will have two elements The first one will be the entire phrase, and the second element will contain just the capture phrase (between the parenthesis).

There are a million variations you can do to account for variations in the HTML, but this is one that maybe can get you started and you could tweak.